# Drawing Slope Triangles in MATLAB loglog plot

Tags: matlab

I have a log-log plot in MATLAB and would like to add a "slope triangle" like [this](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/convergence-plot/).  Any thoughts on how to do this?  Here's a MWE:

```
x = [1000; 2000; 3000; 4000; 5000; 6000; 7000; 8000; 9000; 10000];
y = [0.01; 0.03; 0.05; 0.09; 0.14; 0.2; 0.28; 0.38; 0.48; 0.56];
loglog(x,y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply draw the triangle by hand like so:

```
triang_x = [4000, 5000];  % chose location
triang_y = interp1(x, y, triang_x);
loglog(x, y)
hold on
loglog(triang_x([1,2,2]), triang_y([1,1,2]), 'k')
```

Result:

[image]

To be really precise, this might give small errors for a log-log plot when the grid is really coarse, e.g. for `triang_x = [2500, 3500]` you see that the triangle is not touching the curve exactly, since a linear interpolation is not a straight line in a log-log plot. To fix this, you need to interpolate with `triang_y = exp(interp1(log(x), log(y), log(triang_x)));`.

Comment: Great, thanks for that!  Lastly, would you know a good method for computing and annotating the slope of the hypotenuse?  This data should be quadratic in x, so I'm expecting a slope of about 2.

Comment: You can add annotations at a certain x,y location in a graph using the [text](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function. Have a look at all the available [properties](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) to set font, alignment, etc.